# Applovin banner not show

Tags: java, xml

I am trying this line of code but it does not work for me, could somebody help me?

```
<com.applovin.adview.AppLovinAdView
  android:id="@+id/applovin_banner"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  </com.applovin.adview.AppLovinAdView>
```

java:

```
 AppLovinAdView adView=findViewById(R.id.applovin_banner);
    adView.loadNextAd();
    adView.isShown();
```

Comment: When you say 'not working' is there an error? If not, can you describe the actual behaviour and what you would like it to do instead?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have your SDK key in the Android Manifest file as described [here](https://dash.applovin.com/integration#androidIntegration). Then, you need to go to your AppLovin dashboard and click Monetize -> Manage Apps -> Your App, then flip the "Banner Ads" switch to ON.

Comment: I am not finding the Switch On option in dashboard

Comment: You can try integrating their MAX solution, will provide better monetization through numerous demand partners: https://dash.applovin.com/documentation/mediation

Answer (score 0):

add Dependency in `buld.gradle(Module:app)`

```
//max/applovin dependency
implementation 'com.applovin:applovin-sdk:11.7.0'
//if you use fb with applovin mediation
implementation 'com.applovin.mediation:facebook-adapter:6.12.0.2'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:6.12.0'
```

Add this in `manifest` file above `</application>` tag: sdkKey see in Applovin/Max setting.

```
<meta-data
        android:name="applovin.sdk.key"
        android:value="@string/sdkKey" />
```

In `XML` (with adUnit Id):

```
<com.applovin.mediation.ads.MaxAdView
        xmlns:maxads="http://schemas.applovin.com/android/1.0"
        maxads:adUnitId="3ede******ed"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/maxBannerADDDD"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        />
```

In `java`

first initialize sdk

```
private MaxAdView adView;
//max banner ad

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dictionary);

    //add banner with findViewById
    adView= findViewById(R.id.maxBannerADDDD);
    maxSdkIntialize(); //call sdk initialize function

}

private void maxSdkIntialize(){
    // Max/Applovin SDK initialize
    AppLovinSdk.getInstance( this ).setMediationProvider( "max" );
    AppLovinSdk.initializeSdk(getApplicationContext(), new AppLovinSdk.SdkInitializationListener() {
        public void onSdkInitialized(AppLovinSdkConfiguration appLovinSdkConfiguration) {
            //banner ads after intialize
            funBannerAd();
        }
    });
}
private void funBannerAd(){
    adView.loadAd();
    adView.startAutoRefresh();
}
```

Thanks:)